# Check if user has been timed out in Devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session, devise, timeout

Because I'm using javascript to perform an action instead of a controller method, I need to check if a user has been timed out before that action is rendered. To do this, I tried added and deleting cookies in my application_controller.rb like this:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
  auth.cookies[:signed_in] = 1
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
  auth.cookies.delete :signed_in
end
```

and in my javascript file:

```
myCookie = getCookie("signed_in");
if (myCookie == null)
{
  //redirect to sign in page
} else {
  //perform my action
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var dc = document.cookie;
  var prefix = name + "=";
  var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
  if (begin == -1) {
    begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
    if (begin != 0) return null;
  }
  else
  {
    begin += 2;
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
    if (end == -1) {
    end = dc.length;
    }
  }
  return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work on session timeout, only on logout. I've seen a couple hacky ways to accomplish this, but I can't seem to find anything directly from Devise or Warden to use or override a method to test if a user has been timed-out or take action if a user has been timed-out. I'm on Rails 5 and Devise 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a request that action to the server to see if the user has timedout, because when you set the timeout, that is server side, so there is no change in the client when this time passed out, the only way to know is to make an ajax request to the server to see if the session timedout  `user.timedout?(Time.now.utc)` or make the validation directly on the request for the action (in the controller), the user will always try to run the action, but on the server, you validate if the user has timedout, then you don't let them do it and redirect to the login page.